# Solr 6.6.6 Collection Restore causing problems from single node

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, sharding, solrcloud

I have 2 nodes SolrCloud setup. Version is 6.6.6. I have taken Solr backup from other instance where there are 4 collection shards.

I have used following command to take back that works fine

```
http://10.11.31.11:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=hms&collection=collection1&location=/tmp/solr_backup&async=1001
```

After this I copied backup to one node of Solr Cloud and executed following command to restore.

```
http://10.11.31.12:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=RESTORE&name=hms&location=/home/hduser/Documents/search/data&collection=newCollection&maxShardsPerNode=4&replicationFactor=2&autoAddReplicas=true
```

I got following exception when executed above command

```
<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">500</int><int name="QTime">60</int></lst><str name="Operation restore caused exception:">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Couldn't restore since doesn't exist: file:///home/user12/Documents/search/data/hms</str><lst name="exception"><str name="msg">Couldn't restore since doesn't exist: file:///home/user12/Documents/search/data/hms</str><int name="rspCode">500</int></lst><lst name="error"><lst name="metadata"><str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str><str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str></lst><str name="msg">Couldn't restore since doesn't exist: file:///home/user12/Documents/search/data/hms</str><str name="trace">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Couldn't restore since doesn't exist: file:///home/user12/Documents/search/data/hms
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:300)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:237)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:215)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:749)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:730)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:510)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</str><int name="code">500</int></lst></response>
```

Then I copied the backup data to second node also with exactly same path as on first node and re-executed the restore command. The job was successful.

Does it mean for every backup, it is necessary to copy backup on all nodes of Solr with exactly same path or it is a bug ?

I was expecting that Solr should allow to restore collection from single node and then it should replicate shards on its own ? isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory you're restoring from [has to be available on all the servers](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-restore) at the same path. The path is assumed to be a network share available in a common location on the servers.

> **location**
>
> The location on the shared drive for the restore command to read from.

From the example in the documentation given above:

```
..&name=myBackupName&location=/path/to/my/shared/drive&...
```